# When should commas be used in sentences with 2 or more prepositional phrases?

Tags: punctuation

In this sentence below, for instance, how would commas be used or would commas be used at all?

The sentence:

Please contact the business office of the hospital to qualify for the Uncompensated Care Program to cover the cost of these services.

Comment: I think the sentence needs restructuring, not repunctuating.

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth suggests, the sentence has problems apart from punctuation. Specifically, the wording implies (to me) that merely contacting the business office will enable a person to qualify for the Uncompensated Care Program.

Answer (score 0):

There is no comma required in that sentence. If you feel you need to make the sentences easier to read, then you should break it into two.

For example, Please contact the business office of the hospital to qualify for the Uncompensated Care Program. Doing so covers the cost of these services.

Comment: To me, that seems substantially ***worse*** than the original. You really want to say something like "This program may cover the cost of these services." for your second sentence.

Comment: Don't start your sentences with "This." It goes against grammar guidelines. 

I never said there was anything wrong with the original sentence. What I gave was an alternative if they wanted to break it into two.